# Ubuntu Server Install GUI and Remote Access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-interface, ubuntu-server

How can I install a GUI for a remote server and then access it over RDP (or similar)

I've done a sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop and sudo apt-get install xrdp, but when I go to access it and login, I just get a blank screen. I presume the windowing system hasn't started?

Thanks

Comment: I would also like to know how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Did the desktop fail to start up because there is no display attached?

I think the easiest approach is to use LXDE (Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment) with xrdp.

[Refer This Link](http://www.comtechies.com/2013/02/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu.html)